# @Inject injects null while injecting interface to interceptor

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, interceptor, weld

I have created an interface:

```
interface A {
    Long getA();
}

@Dependent
class B implements A {
    @Resource(lookup="java:comp/EJBContext")
    SessionContext sessionContext;

    public Long getA(){
        //impl
    }
}
```

Now when I inject this into interceptor it throws NPE because injection didn't work:

```
public class InterceptorTest {
    @Inject A a;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object injectTenantId(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        a.getA();
        ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

The above code throws NPE because `A a` is `null`.

Comment: What container are you attempting to run `InterceptorTest` in? (EJB, Web/Servlet, etc)

Comment: How is your interceptor even invoked? Seems that you're missing a `@SomeAnnotation @Interceptor` on the interceptor class.

Comment: I'm using Jboss 7.1.1 (JAVA EE 6), please note that same thing works in JBOss wildfly 8.2.2